# How to switch between different stylesheets using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the size of the browser according to the size of the display using JQuery however it does not seem to work currently.

HTML Code:

```
   <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SmallDesktopScreen.css">
        <link id="newSize" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="LargeScreen.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

        function adjustStyleSheet(width){
        width= parseInt(width);
        if ((width>=1352)&&(width<=1880)){
            $("#newSize").attr("href", "css/SmallDesktopScreen.css");
        }

        else if(width>1881){
            $("#newSize").attr("href", "css/LargeScreen.css");
        }
        }
        <!-- 1352 1881 -->

        $("document").ready(function(){
            $(function() {
                adjustStyleSheet($(this).width());
                $(window).resize(function() {
                adjustStyleSheet($(this).width());
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: If you're depending on screen size to change your CSS, don't use JS. Media queries in a single CSS file will do the trick.

Comment: I've been asked to use scripting for some coursework I'm working on so this seemed like a simple way to do so.

Comment: If they're teaching you to make responsive sites using JS-based style sheet switching... you're at the wrong course.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at media queries but is there a way to use this method?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to switch stylesheets using jquery.

for example

```
var stylesheets = ['style1.css','style2.css'];
var primary_sheet = 0;

if(primary_sheet === 0) {
  $('link').attr('href',stylesheets[0]);
else {
 $('link').attr('href',stylesheets[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing some of your scripts will do the trick.

First of all you cannot, get the link element and set href(which will eventually not work in all the browsers). But you can create one easily.

Check the script code below. This will work.

```
function adjustStyleSheet(width){
    width= parseInt(width);
       var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var link  = document.createElement('link');
        link.id   = "";
        link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
        link.type = 'text/css';
        link.media = 'all';
                var linkHref = "css/SmallDesktopScreen.css";
    if ((width>=1352)&&(width<=1880)){
                linkHref = 'css/SmallDesktopScreen.css';
    }
    else if(width>=1881){
                linkHref = 'css/LargeScreen.css';
    }
        link.href = linkHref;
            head.appendChild(link);
    }
    <!-- 1352 1881 -->

    $("document").ready(function(){
        $(function() {
            adjustStyleSheet($(window).outerWidth());//OuterWidth gets the width of your original screen size not the window size alone.
            $(window).resize(function() {
                adjustStyleSheet($(window).outerWidth());
            });
        });
    });
```

It is good doing stuffs in Javascript or jQuery. But I will support @media queries in CSS for responsive kind of works, which is very easy actually.